# Prevent Intellij IDEA from indenting my comment on else statement

Tags: java, if-statement, intellij-idea, comments

Usually I write comment on else statement like this:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (someStatements) {
            do();
        // comment on else statement
        } else if (someOtherStatements) {
            do();
        // another comment on else statement
        } else {
            do();
        }
    }
}
```

But after IDEA rearranges code I got comments indented:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (someStatements) {
            do();
            // comment on else statement
        } else if (someOtherStatements) {
            do();
            // another comment on else statement
        } else {
            do();
        }
    }
}
```

How do I prevent IDEA code rearranging from intending comments?
Or how to tell IDEA just dont rearrange my comments?

Comment: step one, realize that that is not an else statement, but an else if statement. Totally different matter. Secondly, this has nothing to do with programming, just with the configuration of your IDE

Comment: Well, the comments are part of the previous block and I'm not sure IntelliJ would even be able to distinguish between comments meant for the next line and those meant to be part of the block. You might be able to turn off auto-formatting using something like `// @formatter:off //comment // @formatter:on` (each on a new line of course) but I doubt that would improve issues. I'd suggest thinking about putting the comments elsewhere, e.g. after the else-statement or right in front of it, e.g. `...} //comment else { ...` (again insert line breaks as needed).

Comment: @Stultuske I'm pretty sure Java doesn't have a true else-if, i.e. `else if (condition) { block1 } else { block2 }` is actually just a `else { if(condition) { block1 }  else { block2 }}` (remove the optional braces around the "inner" if-else statement from the latter and you're back to `else if ...`).

Comment: @Stultuske by the way, questions about *"software tools commonly used by programmers"* are [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Thomas whether it is 'true' or not, is irrelevant, what is relevant, is how the IDE looks at the code. It is possible that if he puts those brackets, the comment will go to the spot he wants them

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca yes, but since it's about a software tool, why tagging a programming language?

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Preferences | Editor | Code Style | Java | Code Generation` in the settings and check the `Line comment at first column` checkbox.